# 'size' vs 'ls -l' to get the size of an executable file

Tags: linux, bash, binutils

For the same file, I think the output of `ls -l xxx` is always greater than or equal to the output of `size xxx`.

But when I type `ls -l /bin/ls` the output is:

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 104508  1月 14  2015 /bin/ls
```

For `size /bin/ls`, the output is:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 101298     976    3104  105378   19ba2 /bin/ls
```

Why is `ls` showing less than `size`? **104508 < 105378**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls -l` is telling you the size of the file, while the `size` command tells you the size of the executable image stored in the file -- how much memory it will require when loaded.  Some segments (such as .bss) are zero-initialized rather than requiring data in the file to initialize them, so the the file may well be smaller than the executable image as a result.